# Rails spec testing with multiple projects

Tags: rspec

So I'm looking to test two projects that I have:

1. API that serves as the back end.
2. Public facing platform.

The #2 project makes calls to #1 in order to create/read/update/delete records.

I've heard rumors that rspec testing with two parallel projects is not possible, but I'm interested in at least looking at a few discussions about it.  My google fu may just not be that great today and all I can find are resources for speeding up rspec tests.

Is this possible or will I need to locate some sort of Gem that can help us create fake responses (and need us to create separate tests for each project)?

Comment: Have the same problem 3 `core` projects that I need to run tests for. I have added a gemfile and started testing from the root directory but there are a lot of changes to go through to make that work if at all possible.